# How to print print the first and last numbers from the list do while loop

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, do-while

My original program was

```
    int w;
    w = -10;
    System.out.println(w);
    while (w <= 2020) {
        w++;
    }
    System.out.println(w-1);
```

But now I have to turn it to a do while loop

```
    int w=-10;
    do {
      System.out.println(w);
      w++;    
    } while (w<=2020);
    System.out.println(w-1);
```

What's going on, its not what it was in its original program. How can I make it print first and last number in do while loop?

Comment: `int lastnumber = 2020` and print them before and after..

Comment: Why are you looping anyway? You can just print the numbers `-10` and `2020` and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Take the System.out out of the loop

```
int w=-10;
System.out.println(w);
do {
    w++;    
} 
while (w<=2020);
System.out.println(w-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

take the System.out.println(w); out from inside the loop?  It isn't exactly clear what the question is but that is the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
int w=-10;
System.out.println(w);
do {
    w++;    
} while (w<=2020);
System.out.println(w-1);
```

Comment: Could you also explain your solution with a few words? Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

In your initial while loop, you print out w, and then continue to increment `w` until it reaches 2020, and then outside of the loop, once the condition has been met, you print out `w-1`. It works the way you want it to, right?

Well in the second version, in your **do while** loop, you're printing out `w` the each and every time you increment it. So, print outside of the `do` part, once. And then outside the loop, print `w-1`. It's essentially the same thing as your original **while** loop.

```
int w = -10;
System.out.println(w);
do {
    w++;    
}  
while (w <= 2020);
System.out.println(w-1);
```

Also, what is the point of looping? You could simply just say

```
int w = -10; // first number
int finalNumber = 2020;
System.out.println(w);
System.out.println(lastNumber);
```